# Protractor: Browser.wait() Timeout is timing out on Jasmine defaultTimeoutInterval

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I am currently trying to ensure a negative test using browser.wait(). The test below opens the page, performs a search, clears the search results and waits for the search results to be VISIBLE. The test below should timeout after 5 seconds as the elements will never be visible after they are cleared but it is timing out using the defaultTimeoutInterval (30 seconds) set in the conf.js file. Do I need to change my conf.js settings to use the timeout interval specified in the browser.wait() statement?

I am running Protractor Version 5.3.2

Default Timeout Interval set in conf.js file

```
// Options to be passed to Jasmine.
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true, // Use colors in the command line report. 
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000 // Default time to wait in ms before a test 
fails.
},
```

My test in spec.js file

```
//require page object, actions
var advisorUI = require('../pages/advisor_ui_po.js');
var advisorUIActions = require('../actions/advisor_ui_pa.js');
var advisorUISearchResults = require('../pages/search_results1_po.js');
var advisorUISearchResults2 = require('../pages/search_results2_po.js');
var testExecActions = require('../actions/test_exec_a.js');

//Create instance of the Advisor UI page object
beforeEach(async function () {
 await advisorUI.get();
});

describe('Search By Email', function() {
    it('should display search results', async function() {
        //Execute the Search by email
        var email = browser.params.smoketestdata.email;
        advisorUIActions.searchByEmail(email);
        advisorUIActions.clearSearch();
        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(advisorUISearchResults.getShowingResultsForLabel(), 5000, 'Wait Timeout is working!')); 
    });
});
```

This is the output:

```
λ protractor conf.js --suite regression
Report destination:   screenshots\my-report.html
(node:19008) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use 
os.tmpdir() instead.
[12:04:55] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[12:04:55] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at 
http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
Started
FA Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.

Failures:
1) Search By Email should display search results
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified 
by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified 
by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified 
by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified 
by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 61.941 seconds

[12:06:01] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[12:06:01] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[12:06:01] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
Closing report
[12:06:01] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try returning callback in each test.Please do some assertions and return the callback so that your test will move on.Since you never returned a callback Jasmine thinks your waiting for something.

Make sure to return the callback once you finish completing all steps in a test (i.e) inside a it() block.

Comment: Thanks! I realized it also couldn't ever find the element in the DOM.